# How I can change the color of a TPanel with the VCL Styles enabled?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I need to change the color of a TPanel when the VCL styles are enabled. I tried using and modifying the code listed in the article *[Changing the color of Edit Controls with VCL Styles Enabled](https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/changing-the-color-of-edit-controls-with-vcl-styles-enabled/)*, but it is not working for a TPanel. How I can change the color of a TPanel with the VCL Styles enabled?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`TPanel`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TPanel) doesn't use a style hook to draw the control, so you can't use the technique described in the article. instead you must override the [`paint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCustomPanel.Paint) method.

Check this sample using a interposer class.

```
type

  TPanel=Class(Vcl.ExtCtrls.TPanel)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  End;


Uses
  Vcl.Styles,
  Vcl.Themes;

{$R *.dfm}

{ TPanel }

procedure TPanel.Paint;
const
  Alignments: array[TAlignment] of Longint = (DT_LEFT, DT_RIGHT, DT_CENTER);
  VerticalAlignments: array[TVerticalAlignment] of Longint = (DT_TOP, DT_BOTTOM, DT_VCENTER);
var
  Rect: TRect;
  LColor: TColor;
  LStyle: TCustomStyleServices;
  LDetails: TThemedElementDetails;
  TopColor        : TColor;
  BottomColor     : TColor;
  LBaseColor      : TColor;
  LBaseTopColor   : TColor;
  LBaseBottomColor: TColor;
  Flags: Longint;

  procedure AdjustColors(Bevel: TPanelBevel);
  begin
    TopColor := LBaseTopColor;
    if Bevel = bvLowered then
      TopColor := LBaseBottomColor;
    BottomColor := LBaseBottomColor;
    if Bevel = bvLowered then
      BottomColor := LBaseTopColor;
  end;

begin
  Rect := GetClientRect;

  LBaseColor := Color;//use the color property value to get the background color.
  LBaseTopColor := clBtnHighlight;
  LBaseBottomColor := clBtnShadow;
  LStyle := StyleServices;
  if LStyle.Enabled then
  begin
    LDetails := LStyle.GetElementDetails(tpPanelBevel);
    if LStyle.GetElementColor(LDetails, ecEdgeHighLightColor, LColor) and (LColor <> clNone) then
      LBaseTopColor := LColor;
    if LStyle.GetElementColor(LDetails, ecEdgeShadowColor, LColor) and (LColor <> clNone) then
      LBaseBottomColor := LColor;
  end;

  if BevelOuter <> bvNone then
  begin
    AdjustColors(BevelOuter);
    Frame3D(Canvas, Rect, TopColor, BottomColor, BevelWidth);
  end;
  if not (LStyle.Enabled and (csParentBackground in ControlStyle)) then
    Frame3D(Canvas, Rect, LBaseColor, LBaseColor, BorderWidth)
  else
    InflateRect(Rect, -Integer(BorderWidth), -Integer(BorderWidth));
  if BevelInner <> bvNone then
  begin
    AdjustColors(BevelInner);
    Frame3D(Canvas, Rect, TopColor, BottomColor, BevelWidth);
  end;
  with Canvas do
  begin
    if not LStyle.Enabled or not ParentBackground then
    begin
      Brush.Color := LBaseColor;
      FillRect(Rect);
    end;

    if ShowCaption and (Caption <> '') then
    begin
      Brush.Style := bsClear;
      Font := Self.Font;
      Flags := DT_EXPANDTABS or DT_SINGLELINE or
        VerticalAlignments[VerticalAlignment] or Alignments[Alignment];
      Flags := DrawTextBiDiModeFlags(Flags);
      if LStyle.Enabled then
      begin
        LDetails := LStyle.GetElementDetails(tpPanelBackground);
        if not LStyle.GetElementColor(LDetails, ecTextColor, LColor) or (LColor = clNone) then
          LColor := Font.Color;
        LStyle.DrawText(Handle, LDetails, Caption, Rect, TTextFormatFlags(Flags), LColor)
      end
      else
        DrawText(Handle, Caption, -1, Rect, Flags);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: there seems to be a much easier way, see the other answer

Comment: ecEdgeHighLightColor is close enough, but which would be the actual constant for getting the color used to paint the body of a TPanel?

Comment: I have found the answer: tpPanelBackground + ecFillColor. It will work with most themes but not with 'Auric'. But for Auric it will give a close-enough result. --------------------------
Update: This will always work:  cl:= TStyleManager.ActiveStyle.GetSystemColor(clBtnFace);

Answer (score 23):

In XE5, if you turn off the seClient flag in the StyleElements property, then the Color property works again as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, was upgrading some old Delphi code of mine to Berlin 10.1 Update 2 and it wasn't painting the background of a TPanel control descendent I was using

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis: Glad it helped you. The accepted answer seemed overkill.

Comment: Brilliant! playing around with style elements of a TSpeedButton in XE5, I was able to change its font color and style despite visual theme enabled. May help someone.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @costa's answer, use:

```
StyleElements := StyleElements - [seClient];
```

in the constructor of your TPanel descendent class

or if you just have some TPanel (or descendent class) instance you can do:

```
with myPanel do StyleElements := StyleElements - [seClient];
```

The -[...] syntax is used since the StyleElements is a set

For more on StyleElements read this article:

Tuning VCL Styles for Forms and Controls - http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42812

Comment: This is a much simpler solution. Works on for Delphi 2007 as well using TControlStyle.

{
ControlStyle := MyPanel.ControlStyle;
Exclude(ControlStyle, csParentBackground);
MyPanel.ControlStyle := ControlStyle;
}

Comment: I was on the verge of switching to C# and XAML until I found this solution.