# Custom background color in Delphi with runtime themes enabled

Tags: delphi, colors, themes, vcl

I'm creating a bunch of Panels on runtime and I want to change their color. Color property doesn't work and I don't want turn of runtime themes.

I'm using Delphi XE3.

Comment: Make sure that `ParentColor` is disabled

Comment: When you say themes , do you mean Windows Native Themes or Vcl Styles? if you are using Vcl Styles you can try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309190/how-i-can-change-the-color-of-a-tpanel-with-the-vcl-styles-enabled or remove the `seClient` value from  the  `StyleElements` property.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove seClient from StyleElements and set ParentBackground to false.

```
aPanel.StyleElements :=  Panel1.StyleElements - [seClient];
aPanel.ParentBackground := False;
aPanel.Color := clLime;
```