# There is a TCustomStyleServices in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-7, vcl-styles

In order to override TPanel's Paint procedure to make the background color clwhite in delphi 7, I am following [@RRUZ Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10309468/2087187), but I can't find the TCustomStyleServices class.

There is an alternative to do what I want?

I'm using XPMan resource (IDK if changes anything).

Comment: Setting `Parentbackground` to false and `Color` to clWhite should fit your requirements.

Comment: @bummi, that's the answer!

Comment: @TLama undelete yours, it was covering my comment and showing addition informations.

Comment: @bummi, not now :-) There was a interposer class with overriden `Paint` method which is not needed at all. Hence my edit and deletion. It's enough to use the `TPanel` class as it is with the settings you've mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Delphi7 does not support VCL-Styles, setting Parentbackground to false and Color to clWhite should fit your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can see that the question, your link to, is tagged with VCL Styles tag.
[How I can change the color of a TPanel with the VCL Styles enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309190/)

You can click on tthe tag below the question text and read it's description:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vcl-styles/info

The information says that VCL styles were introduced with Delphi XE2.

Since Delphi 7 was released somewhat before XE2 it can not contain that feature.